# Is there any method in the standard API to inverse retainAll()?

Tags: java, api, list, collections, arraylist

Is there any method which does the following for me in one shot :

```
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("A","B","C","D"));
List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("B","C","E","F"));
List<String> list3 = new ArrayList<String>();
for(String element : list2){
   if(!list1.contains(element))
   list3.add(element);
}
```

As a result list3 should contain elements "E" & "F".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Do you mean?

```
List<String> list3 = new ArrayList<String>(list2);
list3.removeAll(list1);
```

However, doing unions and intersections is usually best done using Sets rather than Lists. (And more efficiently)

```
Set<String> set3 = new LinkedHashSet<String>(set2);
set3.removeAll(set1);
```

Comment: Yes, that does the trick! Thanks. Will there be any adverse effect if I use Lists rather than Sets?

Comment: Sets assume uniqueness of entries and ignore duplicates. Lists are ordered and allow duplicates. I suspect you want the former rather than the latter.

Answer (score 0):

Or with Guava's [`Sets.intersection()`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#intersection%28java.util.Set,%20java.util.Set%29):

```
Lists.newArrayList(Sets.intersection(ImmutableSet.of(list1), ImmutableList.of(list2)));
```